# How to get a code or stacktrace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-config

I am trying to figure out the execution path for some code (i.e. which methods it hits and in what order). Is there a tool, or means through visual studio or the web.config to show the order of functions that a program is going through?

Right now I am placing debug points in certain areas and hoping it hits the right area, but in some cases this is a long slow tedious process.

Comment: " in some cases this is a long slow tedious process." - such is debugging....

Comment: Is there something *specific* you're looking for?

Comment: Ironically, I wasn't even in the right files... I was chasing smoke and mirrors :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to figure out what code is calling a particular method, you could try System.Diagnostics.StackFrame:

```
var s = new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame();
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
```

StackFrame will give you the stack trace for the current thread.
See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx

If you're looking for more detail than that then a profiler may be a better option for you. I've used [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) from JetBrains a bit and it does provide a lot of detail.

**EDIT:** 
ASP.NET also provides [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx) functionality. If you add the following to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

and then add `Trace="true"` to your page directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Trace="true" %>
```

then you'll get a bunch of trace output appended to the bottom of your page when you view it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Some .NET profiling tools can provide this kind of analysis (often called Call Graph Analysis). One that I am aware of is the [ANTS profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=ANTS%20Profiler&c=ANTS_Profiler/help/4.0/AP_Working_with_the_call_graph.htm).

However, if you're looking for a detailed trace of every method that is executed and what parameters were passed - you may find that hard to get with any tool. If that's what you actually need, you may need to use a tool like [PostSHARP](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp) to weave in trace logic on each method call (which you can do with the MethodBoundaryAspect).

Answer (score 0):

Tutorials:

- [Rich Custom Error Handling with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479319.aspx)
- [Exception Handling Advice for ASP.NET Web Applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134127/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081209-1.aspx)

Handlers & Libraries

- [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)
- [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one method I always use is to add either `printf`or `OutputDebugString` in the functions (suppose you have the source code). You can make these debug information only show up in debug version by using some conditional definitions.

Comment: This is kind of what I was trying, and it's what I use when I have a PHP project.

Answer (score 0):

[Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me) shows the order of functions that a .NET program is going through.